# Commerce cart line item to show original price, not the one with discounts subtracted

Tags: 7, commerce

Using Drupal Commerce Kickstart, when the user is at the shopping cart and activated any kind of discount (most of the times, a coupon) the line item price in the Cart table is updated with the discount.

I'd like to show the original price there and let the Summary describe what kind of changes the prices went through.

Here is a screenshot that might help https://www.dropbox.com/s/matvseodarii41m/Screenshot%202014-08-19%2014.46.45.png?dl=0

I'd like the top Price value to be $395 and everything else could stay exactly like this.

How can I make this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like it's supported out of the box https://www.drupal.org/node/2112659

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help you out. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understand your instruction, maybe you could rephrase it ?

In my memory the price of the line item don't change, it's just the total that got influenced.
Is that a fresh install of Kickstart ?
Or does the coupon apply to the product specifically ? Or to the global cart ?

Anyway coupon/discount, if they are from a commerce module then it's triggering with rules, and the shopping cart or the chekout page are just views. You should have a look to these to change theirs behaviors.

In case you are not very familiar to commerce line item, you can check RandyFay video (It's one of the guys whom made commerce), it's very well explained :

- http://vimeo.com/31459435
- http://vimeo.com/22625018
- http://vimeo.com/22617715